# Event.observe not triggered in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, prototypejs

```
Event.observe(
    'size_list',
    'change',
    itemOptions["_hiddenSkuField"].getSkuOfProductBySize
);
```

the `size_list` is a drop-down list with some options. So, this should call a function that will generate me some HTML, but this doesn't happen. Needless to say, it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

I can't see what the problem is, I don't enter the `myFoo` or even the upper `.observe` code, when I try to debug.

```
getSkuOfProductBySize: function() {
        document.getElementById('product-type').value = '';
        document.getElementById('sku_hidden').value = '';
        var selectedIndex = document.getElementById('dropdown_options').value;
        for (var i=0; i<itemOptions["_hiddenSkuField"].products.length; i++) {
            if (itemOptions["_hiddenSkuField"].products[i].size == selectedIndex) {
                document.getElementById('sku_hidden').value = itemOptions["_hiddenSkuField"].products[i].sku;
                itemOptions["_hiddenSkuField"].backupResponse = itemOptions["_hiddenSkuField"].products[i];
                itemOptions["_hiddenSkuField"].callShowHtmlOfButtons(itemOptions["_hiddenSkuField"].products[i]);
                return;
            }
        };
    }
```

`itemOptions["_hiddenSkuField"]` is the global object that I owns all the stuff. :D

UPDATE: 
I tried putting simple `alert()` around the function or the observer and it doesn't work. Also tried with `click` event - no success...

I do front-end development very rarely, but after my struggles with it today, I know why IE is hated so much.

Comment: Can you post the `HTML` related to this ?

Comment: @MaxiWheat - I updated my answer. :) That is the function that will go for generating the HTML.

Comment: which version of PrototypeJS? - the most recent public release is 1.7.1 - Are there multiple elements on the page with the same id?

Comment: You may want to go through this and replace all of your `document.getElementById` instances with `$`, since the former does not return an extended element (i.e.: an element with all of the Prototype extensions added to it) in IE. Only by using one of the Prototype "getters" (`$()` or `$$()` or `Element.extend()`) will you get an object that contains all of the extra Prototype sugar.

Comment: @Walter - Ok, I see your point. But the problem is that I don't even get into the called `getSkuOfProductBySize` function...

Comment: I need to see more context here -- are you inside of a document.observe('dom:loaded', …) callback, or are you at the bottom of the page, so that item (size_list) is already loaded into the DOM for finding? The fact that you aren't even getting your function to call is significant. Remember, Event.observe is an anonymous closure, it can only act on the things that exist at the moment it was closed (unless you provide a finder method inside it, so it can act lazily).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of an ugly solution, since you're using prototype.js, but still you can try with an alternative (if you don't find other solution) - binding an observe event with jQuery:

```
$('#dropdown_options').bind('change', function(){
        itemOptions["_hiddenSkuField"].getSkuOfProductBySize();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Prototype, the above would be

```
$('size_list').observe('change', function(evt){
  itemOptions['_hiddenSkuField'].getSkuOfProductBySize();
});
```

I suspect also that there is a much simpler way to architect this page, such that the objects alone would have all the data they need, and you wouldn't need this "god object" hanging out in the DOM.